# Find the file name in specific directory

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os, re
fileregex = re.compile(r"b(\D)+v.txt")
os.chdir("F:\\")
for file in os.listdir("."):
     mo = fileregex.search(file)
     print(mo.group())
```

It is keep giving me "NonType" Error. I just want to find a file which starts from letter 'b' and ends with 'c'. File name is: brgv.txt and it is located in "Local Dish: F".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As there was a few typos in your question, I think you need to clarify do you actually need the file to starts with "b" and ends with "v" or "c"?

Comment: It is a regular expression. There is a file name brgv.txt located in my local disk "F". I want to find that file by entering it's 1 letter 'b' and end letter 'v'. In the middle is the class. As i am using 'for' loop then it will take all the files in directory which starts from letter 'b' and ends with letter 'v'. I want to find the find but it is keep giving me an error of "Nonetype" file.

Comment: Do you know what does `search` do and what does it return? Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) for help. It does return None at times (namely no match). It literally "search" through the string, so b is not required to be at the beginning.

Comment: There's no need to do this manually with regex. If you're using a recent version of Python 3, you could use [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) from the excellent `pathlib` module for this task. Otherwise, you could use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex in this case. `str.endswith` is enough.

```
if filename.endswith('.txt'):
    filename = filename[:-4]
    if filename[0] == 'b' and filename[-1] == 'v':
        pass # do your work
```